# Collada loading with libxml2

Tags: c++, libxml2, collada

I want to load collada with libxml2.
I get the COLLOADA node, okay, then I try to get the children tag - FAIL, the children tag name is "text".
Why? How can i get the  child of COLLADA node?

```
xmlNode* geometries = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc)->children;

//at THIS point the geometries->name == "text"  WHY?
//IS not it supposed to be "asset"?

while(!xmlStrcmp(geometries->name, (const xmlChar*)"library_geometries")) 
geometries = geometries->next;


xmlNode* mesh = geometries->children;
for(uint i = 0; i < idx; i++)
mesh = mesh->next;
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this method from [this example](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/tree1.c) in the libxml2 website:

```
static void
print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
        }
    }

    print_element_names(cur_node->children);
}
```

Notice that this code checks if a node is of type `XML_ELEMENT_NODE` before printing its name. The `"text"` node that you are reading is the text between the opening and closing tags:

```
<myTag>This is the text between the tags</myTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved.
At every ->children and ->next I had to put another ->next (i don't mean it recursively:)).
Btw., I don't know why, but it works that way.